# Create folder works but permission not inherited

Tags: java, io, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, folder-permissions

I have a piece of Java that create folder(s) on a network mapped drive (Z:)
Script executes on server A (Windows 2008 R2, running as user account "serviceUser") and creates folder(s) on server B (Windows 2003)

The root folder on server B (which is mapped as Z:) has special permission and allows "serviceUser" to create, modify, delete, write, etc. Permissions are set to inherit to child object, so folder created in Z: should get the same permissions as Z: itself.

My code creates 2 folders inside Z: like:

```
File destination = new File("z:\\folder_1\\");
File destination = new File("z:\\folder_1\\subfolder_1\\");
```

Folder "folder_1" gets the correct permissions but "subfolder_1" does not.
After creating those folders, I need to create a file, but as the "subfolder_1" doesn't get permissions, console reports `"Access is denied"` when doing `File fileName = new File("z:\\folder_1\\subfolder_1\\filename.png");`

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the mkdirs command? It will delegate to the OS to create all needed directories in your overall path.

```
File destination = new File("z:\\folder_1\\subfolder_1");
destination.mkdirs();
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better if you first check if the directory exists or not? `if(!destination.exists()) destination.mkdir();`

Comment: I don't think that is a scenario that is occurring for the OP, but there is absolutely nothing wrong with doing that pre-check. The mkdirs call ignores any pre-existing directories in the given path.

Comment: @Perception thanks, I use that do avoid calling the method for each folder, but it doesn't solve the permission issue, unfortunately.

Comment: @user706058 - check the properties of folder_1 after its created. Are the inherit permissions intact on it?

Comment: @Perception - yes, permission gets inherited to `folder_1` but not to `subfolder_1`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use: setReadable() and/or setWritable() on your folder2. This is the only portable pure java way to control file permissions.

Comment: I just tried, same issue with Access is denied message when doing: `File destination = new File(FolderPath);
destination.setReadable(true, false);
destination.setWritable(true, false);`

Answer (score 0):

The only successfull way I found to make this work was to set the user account as an administrator of Server B with full control.